# Any way to bind event handler and call it at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code like the following:

```
var f = function() {...};

$(window).resize(f);

f();
```

As you can see, I'd like `f` to be called every time the window is resized, and also for `f` to be called *once* after I make it the resize event handler.

Is there any way I can make this code shorter/more succinct? Ideally I'd like to eliminate the need for an `f` variable and just make it an anonymous function (i.e. `$(window).resize(function() {...}`), but I need some way of calling the function once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).
resize(function () {console.log("stop resizing me!");}).
resize();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KmhZf/1/

Answer (score 6):

Well you will not make it shorter, but this is one way you can trigger it instead of the `f()`.

```
$(window).resize(f).trigger("resize");
```